# Share VPN Connection on Linux over Ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, ethernet, connection-sharing

I'd like to share a VPN connection on my Linux Mint host, with a guest connected directly via ethernet. This seems to be [trivial on a Windows host](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Windows/1047409882/Sharing-a-VPN-connection-through-an-Ethernet-cable.htm). However the only methods I've seen on Linux are through [IP masquerading](https://howtoforge.com/internet-connection-sharing-masquerading-on-linux) and/or [modifying the firewall directly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148172/share-a-vpn-connection-over-ethernet), which seems dangerous, prone to error, and hard to undo. Is there a method or third-party tool that works similar to how Windows does it?

What I've tried so far is:

1. open the "Advanced Network Configuration" tool (`nm-connection-editor`) and then for the ethernet connection, change the IPV4 method from `Automatic (DHCP)` to `Shared to other computers`
2. use `ifconfig` on the host to figure out the gateway IP of the ethernet connection (it was `10.42.0.1` in my case)
3. set the gateway IP on the guest to `10.42.0.1`
4. configure the guest device to use the static IP `10.42.0.100` (so the host doesn't need to set up a DHCP server)

Now at this point, I can SSH into the guest device via `10.42.0.100`, confirming that there is some sort of connection. However, it doesn't seem like the guest device has any connection to the public internet.

Comment: If your two machines are on the same network you can use hardware VPN and then sharing the connection is fairly easy

Comment: what do you mean by hardware VPN? You mean like one of those routers with build-in VPN support?

Comment: Yes. I use a Cisco RVxx series and it has VPN built in. I do not use the Workstation Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a great detailed guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/194526), and it turns out I was way over-complicating it. The answer was to simply set the guest/client to use automatic DHCP (instead of a static IP), and everything else was handled automagically! Thanks linux!

I also confirmed that my host's VPN kill-switch worked properly, and the client had zero internet when I disconnected the VPN on the host.

(I originally thought that getting DHCP working would be a pain, after reading two stackexchange answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/982466) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/708185))

Note that the guide above also details how to get it working with a static client IP, but unfortunately those steps didn't work for me. When I would try to SSH in, I would get "no route to host" errors. Ideally I would have wanted a static IP since my client is a raspberry pi, and I wanted a headless setup, but plugging in an external monitor to get the client IP was a small compromise.

(I think the [previously mentioned guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148172/share-a-vpn-connection-over-ethernet) involving editing firewalls was actually mainly about getting a "VPN kill-switch" working. But since my host already has a VPN kill-switch, I actually didn't need all that. In fact I think I could have gotten the `10.42.0.100` static IP working if I had simply enabled [IP forwarding](https://openvpn.net/faq/what-is-and-how-do-i-enable-ip-forwarding-on-linux/), but I didn't want to mess with my setup further)